# ¿Qué significa “ostream &os”?

Tags: c++, ostream

He visto que en muchas ocasiones se utiliza esto `ostream &os`. He leído un poco en ingles pero no me queda claro.

¿Alguien podría aportar algo de luz sobre este tema en español?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Significa "*una referencia llamada `os` a un objeto de tipo `ostream`*".

---

Un objeto de tipo `ostream` es un flujo de datos (***stream***) de salida (***o***utput), de este flujo de salida se hereda por ejemplo la salida a archivo (`ofstream`: ***o***utput **f**ile **stream**) o la salida a texto (`ostringstream`: ***o***utput **string** **stream**), por lo tanto usando `ostream` podemos dirigir la salida a consola, archivo, texto u otros flujos de datos derivados:

```
struct Objeto {};
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Objeto &objeto)
//  Se puede llamar como prefieras --> ^
{
    return o << "Mostramos el objeto " << &objeto;
}

int main()
{
    Objeto obj;
    std::ofstream archivo{"archivo.txt"};
    std::ostringstream texto;

    archivo << obj;   // Enviamos el objeto a un flujo de archivo.
    texto << obj;     // Enviamos el objeto a un flujo de texto.
    std::cout << obj; // Enviamos el objeto al búfer de consola.

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDBasMwDIbP0VOIDEoHXbpzY3rbsewZXNfpXBIrOHIphLzYrnuwzE7ddHQMdrL86/9@Cam2fTkqNY5PxqraHzQKQx07LZst3LXut1TdJAiFV4zv@5Nmwn4og3LYbFIMLqjVTjI5IZYPjRUqst2M0vQ8Qw@Z0@ydRUIhMN9FQjbUoa6TCfPYWVw/JQwAxjI20tjlxN8TS8iuU9PCKJ36MGfq81QUfOF8mG3BZewxeVlfYjxkyRuHxkxEXK/xzZ7Nw1oSvcWq9ifCcKTbBMimoB/0//iJKtJmijzPCX/QNe6/PivtIhxPS7UsYL7mazjUOH4D)</kbd>. Si ejecutas el programa en tu máquina y abres el archivo `archivo.txt` verás que se ha escrito el texto:

> ```
> Mostramos el objeto 0xv4l0rh354d3c1m4l
> ```

Que será lo mismo que se mostró por consola y lo mismo que contiene el flujo de texto, puedes comprobarlo así:

```
std::cout << texto.str();
```